# C# MVC TextBoxFor Currency Prefix

Tags: c#, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, asp.net-mvc-4

Is it possible with either Bootstrap, HTML5 or jQuery to have a currency prefix within the input field as a display element and not part of the actual input value?

For example I wish to display £550.00 in the Amount field, but the data as 550.00

I have tried using w2ui, jQuery Price Format and jQuery maskMoney, all 3 do the same job basically, they can indeed prefix or suffix, but they don't actually store a value in the input, so posting data returns a null value.

**Model.cs**

```
[DisplayFormat(DataFormatString = "{0:F2}", ApplyFormatInEditMode = true)]
public double Amount { get; set; }
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="col-sm-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">Amount</span>
        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.Amount, new { @class = "form-control", @Value = @ViewBag.Amount, placeholder = "Amount", @Id = "Amount" })
    </div>
</div>

// Dynamically setting value of field
$('#Amount').val(data.Amount);

// w2ui example
$('#Amount').val(data.Amount).w2field('money', { moneySymbol: '£' });

// jQuery Price Format example
$('#Amount').val(data.Amount).priceFormat({
    prefix: '£'
});
```

I realise I can use another field to store the numeric value, but I have quite a few fields I need to display which are initially dynamically populated, but can be overridden by the user. So duplicating fields, one for display input and one hidden to store inputted data seems over kill.

Any assistance would be much appreciated :-)

Answer (score 0):

I recommend wrapping your input with a span:

```
<span class="currency">£ @Html.TextBoxFor()</span>
```

And modifying that with css to make it format nicely for yourself. Such as [this](http://jsfiddle.net/xLb9z2po/120/).

Or just add it as a label:

```
<label for="currencyInput">Amount in £</label>
```

Otherwise, you'll be stuck trying to remove / add the prefix everywhere. Keep your input as the actual value.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I have implemented a ModelBinder which resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

The issue wasn't with any of the jQuery libraries but the fact that the form was posting a string, whereas the model was expecting a double.

So I have implemented a ModelBinder to allow the post of string data containing the '£' pound sign and convert to a double.

**MyModelBinder.cs**

```
namespace WebApplication1.Models
{
    public class MyModelBinder : DefaultModelBinder
    {
        protected override object GetPropertyValue(ControllerContext controllerContext, ModelBindingContext bindingContext, System.ComponentModel.PropertyDescriptor propertyDescriptor, IModelBinder propertyBinder)
        {
            if (propertyDescriptor.ComponentType == typeof(MyModel))
            {
                if (propertyDescriptor.Name == "Amount")
                {
                    var obj = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue("Amount");

                    return Convert.ToDouble(obj.AttemptedValue.Replace("£", ""));
                }
            }

            return base.GetPropertyValue(controllerContext, bindingContext, propertyDescriptor, propertyBinder);
        }
    }
}
```

**HomeController.cs**

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult Index([ModelBinder(typeof(MyModelBinder))]MyModel model)
```

**HTML**

```
$('#Amount').val(data.Amount).priceFormat({
    prefix: '£'
});
```

I hope this proves useful to others.